# How to make a Subscript cursor?

Tags: html, css

Already i have made a superscript cursor using below code.How to make a cursor as subscript ?

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    from, to { border-color: transparent }
    50% { border-color: red }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
    from, to { border-color: transparent }
    50% { border-color: red }
}

body {
    width:1px;
    height:9px;
    border-left:5px solid red;
    -webkit-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
    -moz-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
}
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vrEnp/836/)

Output :

[image]

How to place as below :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work some border and padding modifications:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    from, to { border-color: transparent }
    50% { border-color: red }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
    from, to { border-color: transparent }
    50% { border-color: red }
}

body {
    width:0px;
    height:2px;
    padding-bottom:9px;
    padding-left:5px;
    border-bottom:10px solid red;
    -webkit-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
    -moz-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
}
```

```html
subscript
```